# Webgrid ,first td should be diffrent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I am planing to use Webgrid  of MVC3/MVC4

But all my rows in the table should have same column format except for the first one.

In the first row there should be a  text box that span all the columns of the table.
All other rows  should be populated with he list i  give as input

How  can I achieve this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   function createSearchTextBox(){
        var numberOfColumns = $("#grid >table").find("th").length;
        var firstTableRow = "<tr><td id='searchBox'colspan='" + numberOfColumns + "' ><input type='text'></input></td></tr>";
        $("#grid >table tr:first").after(firstTableRow);
        PlaceCheckBoxInHeader();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can do that currently is with client-side scripting after the grid has rendered. jQuery would be a good option.

Comment: How can i run Some client side script after the table is rendered?

Comment: How can i get the table rendering completed event

Comment: There is no event as such. Once your server side code has executed, the HTML is sent to the browser. Once it is displayed there, you can further manipulate the DOM (Document Object Model) using client side scripting. Javascript is the most popular way to do this, and jQuery is a library that makes it easy to work with javascript.